# how to get the access token from facebook ios sdk 3.1?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

how to get the access token from facebook ios sdk 3.1?

I'm already getting the facebook login. Once the login is completed, the app comes to foreground. Although I could not yet figure out how to get the access token from this.

I get null from [[FBSession activeSession] accessToken]; command.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this you are facing similar error like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745235/handle-invalid-accesstoken-with-fbsession-openactivesessionwithreadpermissions-i

Answer (score 6):

`accessToken` is deprecated so you should use this ...

```
[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData];
```

This will help you......

Answer (score 3):

`FBSession.accessToken`, an `NSString*`, is deprecated.  FB documentation suggests using `(FBAccessTokenData*) accessTokenData` instead.  `FBAccessTokenData` has a field, `(NSString*) accessToken`, so the solution is to substitute

```
[FBSession activeSession].accessToken
```

with

```
[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken
```

**EDIT:**  We're up to SDK 3.8 at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

Hello try this one works perfectly for me,

> [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Try this:

```
[session accessTokenData].accessToken
```