# Facebook posting procedure fails with error "The access token was invalidated on the device"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting the error when trying to post to FB wall:

```
{
    code = 190;
    message = "The access token was invalidated on the device.";
    type = OAuthException;
}
```

I use the Social framework and I'm getting access to account through account store, asking for appropriate permissions. All permissions are granted so I don't even know what causes this error.
If you need a code just ask me which exactly because there is a lot of it.
P.s. it seems that I have not been authorized but how could it be as I'm granted with all permissions needed?

Comment: follow this url it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644229/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor

Comment: Very funny = ))) This is my own question..no it didn't help me.

Comment: you Can check this link it may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745235/handle-invalid-accesstoken-with-fbsession-openactivesessionwithreadpermissions-i

Comment: you Can check this link it may help you
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745235/handle-invalid-accesstoken-with-fbsession-openactivesessionwithreadpermissions-i