# iOS Facebook SDK Login Failure after Deleting Facebook Account and Restoring it

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook iOS SDK to allow users to log in to my app. This has been working flawlessly until I disabled and re-enabled my Facebook account during testing. Now, I can still login through my website using the Facebook login but not the iOS Device. I am getting the following error:

```
  <h1>OAuthException at /login/facebook-session</h1>
  <pre class="exception_value">The access token was invalidated on the device. (error code 190)</pre>
```

How do I fix this on the device? Can I have the App ask the user to validate the device for Facebook integration again?

I've read this post, but there were no resolutions there:
[Facebook posting procedure fails with error "The access token was invalidated on the device"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723813/facebook-posting-procedure-fails-with-error-the-access-token-was-invalidated-on)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to clear the token and then it works:

```
    // Ensure facebook is logged out
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```