# Facebook login give me already authorized this app everytime

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

I am working on facebook integration using Facebook SDK .. i have uibutton where i am using it to login to facebook and share details on facebook

I am using FBSession to login

```
 [FBSession.activeSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state,NSError *error) {
```

I am able to login to facebook .. but when i try to share everytime it goes to authorization page even when user has already authorized . i dont want this page to appear other than first time . how to make sure this page doesnt appear everytime user wants to share on facebook

in plist file i have given correct app id and in urlscheme fbappid as well and in my appdelegate i have added handleopenurl , open session

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that the title of question doesn't correspond its content :) The pavan309's answer is good for the *title* meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have already given permission for this particular app on facebook.
Try using a new account you will be asked for permissions.

**EDIT**

Try using

```
`+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:(NSArray*)readPermissions
                            allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                       completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;`
```

use the session object that comes in completionHandler

Comment: new account as in which account ?? and do u have a sample code ?

Comment: Answer for the title : Any other facebook account which was not authorised previously.

If you uses the method which I have given in the answer you dont need to switch to facebook app every time you share

Comment: ..where should i add this method ? ..do u have example where they have used this method ?

Comment: You can see the example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745235/handle-invalid-accesstoken-with-fbsession-openactivesessionwithreadpermissions-i)

Comment: i even tried that it still asking me authorize ...i'll give me project can  u help me out if its ok with u

Comment: Sure, I can give it a try. 
It will ask you for the very first time if you use it from then it will not.

Comment: this is the link to my project .https://www.dropbox.com/s/hw57rm9axsr47tq/facebookTest%20copy%202.zip

Comment: It is working fine for me,
Only the first time I was asked for the login, I have clicked on cancel. Again I have clicked announce, it didnt navigate me to facebook.
Next I have killed the application and then I have rerun the application, even then it didnt navigate me to facebook.

Comment: it didnt ask for authrorization page when the app is opened multiple times ..and btw when i click announce button first time it doesnt show friends ..when i click announce button second time it shows friends list ..why is that ..when i click announce button first time it should show friends list

Comment: I will look into that after some time and let you know.

Comment: Pavan were u able to look into it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28686/discussion-between-pavan309-and-raptor)

Comment: .just one more thing .. when i click announce button first time it navigates to fb to get authorization ..after i click OK ..it doesnt show friends list unless i click the button once again (this happens first time only)

Answer (score 2):

In order to be not asked whether you want to authorize your app or not (despite you're authorized already) you have to reuse you old token. You're making a new one every time, therefore facebook API asks your confirmation.

**EDIT :** 
 (suggested by @Slavco Petkovski in comments)

Validate access token you have saved before using it:

```
if (![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] ||
      [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].expirationDate.timeIntervalSince1970 < now.timeIntervalSince1970) {
    // initiate request for a new token
}
```

Comment: (comment for deleted comment) Not exactly. At the moment when I was responding, we (developers) were better keep access token somewhere (in keychain, database, coredata or whatever) and reuse it each time you want to work with FB. But since each token has an expiration date you had to check first if it was still valid

Comment: Yes, i edited in question. I do this if (![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] && ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].expirationDate.timeIntervalSince1970 < now.timeIntervalSince1970) ) then get new one

Comment: Well, looks good to me even though it was quite a time since I've worked with FB SDK )

Comment: @SlavcoPetkovski In the format the edition was made before I evaluated it as not worth to be added to the answer. If you're 100% sure the code you suggest in comment is working, you may create an edition once again with a code chunk and I'll accept it