# Switching between two accounts using IOS6 settings

Tags: facebook, ios6

I've been trying for the past two days to connect to multiple accounts for my app, without success.

I've read that there was potentially a problem with Facebook SDK not clearing the cached token correctly. I am using version 3.1.1.

Here is how it goes.

From fresh install:

- Connect to account 1.
- Launch game and login successfully. Everything is fine.
- Close the game
- Goto settings and change to account 2.
- Launch game, login failed.

I Am receiving that error code from openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions : **FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed**
And even if I press the OK button when Facebook is asking for my permission to access my info, the granted variable that comes back says NO.

The research I did brought me multiple solutions that failed, unfortunately.
I tried resynchronizing with this function:

```
- (void)fbResync
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore;
    ACAccountType *accountTypeFB;
    if ((accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init]) && (accountTypeFB = [accountStore     accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook] ) )
    {

    NSArray *fbAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountTypeFB];
    id account;
    if (fbAccounts && [fbAccounts count] > 0 && (account = [fbAccounts objectAtIndex:0]))
    {

        [accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:account completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error)
        {
            //we don't actually need to inspect renewResult or error.
            if (error){

            }
        }];
    }
}
```

fbAccounts always return me an empty array. So I cannot really resynchronize.

I also tried to clear facebook token in my  status switch

```
case FBSessionStateClosed:
case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
{
     [FBSession.activeSession close];
     [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
     // Clear out the Facebook instance


     [self.facebook logout];
     self.facebook.accessToken = nil;
     self.facebook.expirationDate = nil                                       

}break;
```

No matter what I do, It seems that I cannot completely get rid of my facebook token.
The only way I found was to reset the settings of the IPAD which is not a solution.

Does anybody have more options I could try?

Thanks!

Tickets I'm aware of :

- [Facebook authorization fails on iOS6 when switching FB account on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838118/facebook-authorization-fails-on-ios6-when-switching-fb-account-on-device)
- [Facebook SDK 3.1 - Error validating access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601191/facebook-sdk-3-1-error-validating-access-token)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612629/expired-access-token-after-openactivesession-for-facebook-ios-sdk

Using Ben Flynn answer worked for me.

Comment: @user1055230 did you figure it out? I'm having the exact same problem.